# Delete from end of line in visual block mode

Tags: replace, visual-block

If i've got the code

```
hello 
hellllo
hello
```

i can insert code before or after all of the lines by using I or A in visual block mode, respectively. How can I delete the last x characters? I'm aware that I can do it with s/o// (where o would require more specific text realistically) but isn't there visual block command?

Comment: do you want to delete just the `o`s or `o`, `llo`, `o`?

Answer (score 6):

One way would be to select the lines (using any of the visual modes: block, line, or regular characterwise) and then type the command:

```
:norm! $xxx
```

Vim will pre-populate the command line with a range when you press <kbd>:</kbd> so the actual command you will execute is:

```
:'<,'>norm! $xxx
```

This acts like visiting each line and typing <kbd>$</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>. (See `:help :normal`.)

Note that, because of the way the `x` command handles a range, `:norm!$3x` won't work. (However, if your `virtualedit` setting contains `onemore` or `all` then you can use a count with a command like `:norm!$ld3h`: the original command given won't work.)

Comment: Very nice, this works like a charm for deleting multiple single-line HTML comments with :norm!04x$3X

Comment: (counting <!-- comment --> spaces, :norm!05x$4X)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`x` and `d`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#v_x) in visual (block, line) mode. They will delete exactly the selected text.  This means you can normally not do things like "delete the last three chars of all selected line" (unless all the lines are the same length, then you can with visual block mode).

**But** according to [How do you change the last n characters for a range of lines?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8370/how-do-you-change-the-last-n-characters-for-a-range-of-lines) there is a trick: Use [`:right`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:right) to first right align the text, remove your chars with visual block mode and the `:left` align the text again.

Comment: TIL about the right and last trick, amazing. thank you

Comment: I tried and some lines weren't aligned. Reading :h right, it was because :right aligns them at column 80 by default, which will leave longer lines unaligned. That can be changed by adding the desired width after it (e.g., :right 120).